# Configurable Product Image were not changing by selecting the Color in magento2

Tags: magento2.3

In my PDP Page (Product Discription Page), while I am selecting a color the Product image not changing according to that Color.

Please refer the site below URL: [Click Here](https://winecountrymotorsports.com/product_info.php/products_id/1106?osCsid=ed9648b51b311709b24066affe9f6cf8)

```
https://winecountrymotorsports.com/product_info.php/products_id/1106?osCsid=ed9648b51b311709b24066affe9f6cf8
```

**Please suggest me any solution as soon as possible.**

Comment: https://bsscommerce.com/blog/2-easy-steps-to-add-color-swatch-in-magento-2/

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is default process in magento 2. but I have uploaded the products through the csv file. The csv file getting from os commerce by using manual php program. After imported the products, this issue is happened.